# Print delay in asp.net using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, printing, wkhtmltopdf

I have deployed an asp.net application in IIS and is accessible via mobile phone or tab using the deployed system IP when ever both the device using same router for Wi-Fi access. I am using wkhtmltopdf to generate PDF file in web pages. When I give print command from computer where I have configured IIS, the print comes faster. But when the same print command is fired from mobile or any other device, print is taking so much delay to generate PDF file.

```
PdfConvert.ConvertHtmlToPdf(new PdfDocument
 {
   Html = "<p class=\"para\">Content with special style.</p><p>Content without style</p>",
 }, new PdfOutput
 {
   OutputFilePath = @print_path + "Order NO.pdf"
 });
```

Comment: ....have you done any tracing, benchmarking, or profiling to investigate the performance issues? If not, **why not**?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I found the issue myself, the problem was not with PDF generation or wkhtmltopdf. Inside the save command, I have taken the system ID for inserting the system ID to database. When i was operating from the web hosted server the application was able to ge the system ID fast. But when using the application from a tab or mobile using the IP of web hosted server the time was taking for getting the system ID of the android or other device. When i gave static value to system ID the problem solved. It took two days of mine to get to the real issue. Thanks for valuable time.